# Perl: passing two hashes to sub

Tags: perl, hash, parameter-passing

Below is a small sub to calculate distance between two points by passing two hashes each containing the x and y coordinates. I get a "syntax error near ]{" fatal error at the line calling the sub. Just started on Perl yesterday, not entirely sure what I am doing. How do I pass two hashes to a sub to return a value? Tried [this](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=932374) without much success and not sure what I need to work on (hope it is ok to refer to an outside link).

```
%dot1 = ('x'=>5, 'y'=>6);
%dot2 = ('x'=>7, 'y'=>8);

sub dist {
    my (%hash1) = @_[0];
    my (%hash2) = @_[1];

    $dist = ((@_[0]{'x'}-@_[1]{'x'})**2 + (@_[0]{'y'}-@_[1]{'y'})**2)**0.5;
}


$D = dist(\%dot1,\%dot2);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First and foremost, you should start every file with

```
use strict;
use warnings;
```

This lets Perl catch the most obvious errors in code.

---

This part is mostly fine, but under `use strict` Perl will complain about `%dot1` and `%dot2` being undeclared (and without `strict` they will be implicitly global, which is usually not what you want):

```
%dot1 = ('x'=>5, 'y'=>6);
%dot2 = ('x'=>7, 'y'=>8);
```

Change it to

```
my %dot1 = ('x'=>5, 'y'=>6);
my %dot2 = ('x'=>7, 'y'=>8);
```

---

The call

```
$D = dist(\%dot1,\%dot2);
```

has the same problem: It should be

```
my $D = dist(\%dot1,\%dot2);
```

What it does is pass references to `%dot1` and `%dot2` to the sub `dist`.

---

```
    my (%hash1) = @_[0];
```

This line doesn't make much sense: `@_[0]` is a list slice, returning a list of elements of `@_` corresponding to the indices `0`. In other words, it's a one-element slice and better written as `$_[0]`, accessing the single element directly.

But in either case it doesn't make sense to assign a single element to a hash. Perl will interpret it as a key and set the corresponding value to `undef`. Your call passed `\%dot1` as the first argument, so `$_[0]` is a reference to a hash. By using it as a hash key, Perl will convert it to a string, yielding something like `"HASH(0x0075ADD40)"`.

Your choices at this point are to either dereference the reference right there and make a copy:

```
    my %hash1 = %{ $_[0] };   # effectively performs %hash1 = %dot1
```

Or keep the reference and dereference it each time you need access to the hash:

```
    my $hashref1 = $_[0];     # $hashref1->{foo} accesses $dot1{foo} directly
```

---

```
    $dist = ((@_[0]{'x'}-@_[1]{'x'})**2 + (@_[0]{'y'}-@_[1]{'y'})**2)**0.5;
```

There are a few issues here. First, you don't need the (implicitly global) variable `$dist`. You just want to return a value from the sub, which can be done with `return`. Then, as explained above, `@_[0]` and `@_[1]` should be `$_[0]` and `$_[1]`, respectively. Fixing that we get

```
    return (($_[0]{'x'} - $_[1]{'x'}) ** 2 + ($_[0]{'y'} - $_[1]{'y'}) ** 2) ** 0.5;
```

This does indeed work (`$_[0]{'x'}` is syntactic sugar for `$_[0]->{'x'}`, i.e. this expression dereferences the hash reference stored in `$_[0]` to reach the `'x'` key of `%dot1`).

But we didn't use the variables we just created at all. Depending on which way you want to go, you should replace `$_[0]{foo}` by either `$hash1{foo}` or `$hashref1->{foo}` (and similar for `$_[1]` and `%hash2`/`$hashref2`).

Finally, instead of `** 0.5` we can just use `sqrt`.

---

Here's how I'd write it:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

sub dist {
    my ($p1, $p2) = @_;
    return sqrt(($p1->{x} - $p2->{x}) ** 2 + ($p1->{y} - $p2->{y}) ** 2);
}

my %dot1 = (x => 5, y => 6);
my %dot2 = (x => 7, y => 8);

my $D = dist(\%dot1, \%dot2);

print "Result: $D\n";
```

Comment: That is really helpful @melpomene. Thank you for taking the trouble to explain it so well.

Comment: @user110084 See https://p3rl.org/REF for more information about references.

Answer (score 2):

Many problems here, I'm afraid.

First you, need to add `use strict` and `use warnings` to your code. This will point out many errors. Mainly places where you use `@array[index]` but should have used `$array[index]`. You also don't declare any of your variables.

Fixing all of that gives me this code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

my %dot1 = ('x'=>5, 'y'=>6);
my %dot2 = ('x'=>7, 'y'=>8);

sub dist {
    my (%hash1) = $_[0];
    my (%hash2) = $_[1];

    my $dist = (($_[0]{'x'}-$_[1]{'x'})**2 + ($_[0]{'y'}-$_[1]{'y'})**2)**0.5;
}


my $D = dist(\%dot1,\%dot2);

say $D;
```

This still doesn't work. I get:

```
$ perl twohash
Reference found where even-sized list expected at twohash line 11.
Reference found where even-sized list expected at twohash line 12.
2.82842712474619
```

The errors are where you are assigning the two arguments you pass into `dist()`.

```
my (%hash1) = $_[0];
my (%hash2) = $_[1];
```

You are passing references to hashes, not the hashes themselves (And you're right to do that), but this means that you get scalars, not hashes, in the subroutine. So those lines need to be:

```
my ($hash1) = $_[0];
my ($hash2) = $_[1];
```

Making those changes, the code now works and gives the result "2.82842712474619".

I'll just point out one further strangeness in your code - you assign the parameters to the function to two lexical variables (`$hash1` and `$hash2`) but you then ignore those variables and instead go directly to `@_` for this data. I expect you actually want:

```
my $dist = (($hash1->{'x'}-$hash2->{'x'})**2 + ($hash1->{'y'}-$hash2->{'y'})**2)**0.5;
```

Note, I've changed `$_[0]{'x'}` to `$hash1->{'x'}` as you have a reference to a hash.

All in all, this code is a bit of a mess and I suggest you go back to the very earliest chapters of whatever book you are learning Perl from.

Answer (score -1):

Could you please try this:

```
use Data::Dumper;

my %dot1 = ('x'=>5, 'y'=>6);
my %dot2 = ('x'=>7, 'y'=>8);

sub dist {
    my %hash1 = @_[0];
    my %hash2 = @_[1];
   $dist = ((@_[0]->{'x'}-@_[1]->{'x'})**2 + (@_[0]->{'y'}-@_[1]->{'y'})**2)**0.5;
   }

$D = dist(\%dot1,\%dot2);

print $D;
```

Comment: Why didn't you fix all the `@_[0]` errors to `$_[0]`?

Comment: Why did you add `Data::Dumper`?

Comment: @DaveCross: Sure we can do this `@_[0]` to `$_[0]`.

Comment: @melpomene: Just I want to confirm the `hash` values with `Dumper`.

Comment: @ssr1012: I know that we **can** do it. I wondered why you **didn't** do it - given that it was the most obvious error in the original code.

Comment: @DaveCross: I copied the code and compiled without modification rather than `@_[0]->{'x'}`. Also without warnings `-w` I did the same. Hence I couldn't update that `array` into `scalar indexing`. Do you need apologizes from me. Anyway I regret for this which I have not done.

Comment: thank you @ssr1012. Would have been clueless about using ->! Not come across that so far.

Comment: @user110084: You don't need to use  the `->` here though. `$_[0]{'x'}` and `$_[0]->{'x'}` both do exactly the same thing.

Comment: I realise I should dig deeper before asking. Where can I read up on "->" and related stuff? Not even sure what to search...

Comment: @user110084: To read up on this stuff try [perldoc perlreftut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html), [perldoc perlref](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html) and [perldoc perldsc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html). But I think you'd be well advised to get a good book as well.